# How to execute function in backend (Next.js) after 10 min

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have booking app in Next.js and MongoDB. Users can make reservations and have 10min to make payment, if user doesn't make payment, reservation will be deleted. All is working great while app is open. Frontend send req to backend after 10min and backend delete reservation.
BUT, if app is closed, frontend doesn't send req to backend.
I am trying to set setTimeout in backend and execute function after 10min.

Someone told me :

"
You can't use setTimeout for this. What happens when your server crashes, or you deploy a new version and restart the app? Every existing interval would be lost.
"

Looking for any idea or link or npm, anything how to fix this issue?

here is code in backend with setTimeout.

```
const id = req.body.userID    // user ID
const bookingDetails = await Booking.find({ user: id })
       .sort({ createdAt: -1 })


       let status = ''
       let reservationId = ''

        bookingDetails.map(item => {
            status = item.status    
            reservationId = item.id
          }) 

 if(reservationId) {
         const reservation = await Booking.find({ _id: reservationId })
      
         setTimeout( async () => {

          if(bookingDetails && status === 'unPaid') {
            
              await Booking.findByIdAndDelete( reservation )
              console.log(' reservation deleted from server side ')
              
          } else {
            return 
          }

        },603000)
      }
```

Question is how to execute function in backend after 10min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a high-level overview of how you can implement a more reliable solution using a job queue system:

**A job queue system is a software component that helps manage and execute tasks asynchronously in a distributed and scalable manner. It is used to decouple time-consuming or resource-intensive tasks from the main application logic, allowing them to be processed independently and efficiently.**

1.Set up a job queue system: First, you need to set up a job queue system (e.g., Bull, Agenda, or any other suitable one). These job queues are responsible for scheduling and executing tasks asynchronously.

you can install Bull **npm install bull**

```js
const Queue = require('bull');

// Create a new Bull queue with the name "myFunctionQueue"
const myFunctionQueue = new Queue('myFunctionQueue', {
  redis: {
    host: 'localhost', // Redis server host
    port: 6379, // Redis server port
  },
});

module.exports = myFunctionQueue;
```

2.Create a worker: Write a worker function that contains the logic of the task you want to execute after 10 minutes.

```js
// import myFunctionWorker.js 
const myFunctionQueue = require('in whichever file you have myfunctionWorker.js');

myFunctionQueue.process(async (job) => {
  // Your function logic goes here
});
```

3.Schedule the task: When the user triggers the action that should execute the function after 10 minutes, enqueue a job in the job queue system with a delay of 10 minutes.

4.The worker executes the task: The job queue system will handle the delayed job and execute the worker function after the specified delay, even if your server restarts in the meantime.

```js
const myFunctionQueue = require('in whichever file you have myfunctionWorker.js');

export default function handler(req, res) {
  // Enqueue the job with a 10-minute delay
  myFunctionQueue.add({}, { delay: 600000 });

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Function execution scheduled.' });
}
```

I think this will help you to manage your code if it doesn't so let me know I will try my best to help you